# Nokia HERE APIs. How to use "app_id"?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps, here-api

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone 8 and I'm using the Nokia HERE APIs. However I don't know how to use the "app_id" number generated for me by the HERE Developer website. Even this website seems not to be of much help. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_appidandtoken) from Nokia Developer Center 
showing how to use the app_id (ApplicationID) to call Here services.

You also need an `AuthenticationToken`, which you should have received with the ApplicationID.